# Strange div alignment with alignment in chrome on the new macbook 13"

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I'm working on a site and experiencing a weird alignment issue. In cross browser testing the issue appears to occur only on a new macbook 13" in chrome. [image: screen shot of issue]

On all other os/browsers that I've tested it appears like this: [image: screenshot of all other browsers]

The only thing I can think of is that I am using VH for my font size. I did this for scaling purposes. Not sure if the issue is with the CSS, or a weird resolution issue with the new macbooks

```
p {
    font-size: 2.35vh;
    line-height: 3.5vh;
}
```

Comment: I think I was able to duplicate the issue... Possibly the browser zoom: https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/212760/4474881/ioI7ILecO3G1Cbg/upload.png

Comment: The texts are different. So in some font sizes, the left text takes up a different number of lines than the right. I don't think there's much you can do about that.